# Web Scraping Incentive Table

Tags: python, web-scraping, energy

I am trying to web scrape the Incentive Step Tracker table from the URL below. I am only interested in Small Residential Storage.

I got somewhere close but not exactly the full table. Please help finish my code and transform the result into CSV format so I can save to a local folder.

Here is my code:

```
# import libraries
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import csv

urlpage='https://www.selfgenca.com/home/program_metrics/'

page = urllib.request.urlopen(urlpage)
# parse the html using beautiful soup and store in variable 'soup'
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
print(soup)

table = soup.find('table',{'class': 'table'}).find_all('tbody',{'data-t': 'Small Residential Storage'})[0]
results = table.find_all('tr')
print(results)
```

Here is the table I want to scrape:

[Ideal Output Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hX7GL.png)

Comment: https://www.selfgenca.com/terms_of_use/ **You may not use any robot, spider or other automatic device, process or means to access, retrieve, scrape, reverse engineer, compile, create derivative works, publically display or otherwise distribute any portion of the Site or the Platform.**

Comment: Is the problem that you don't see the values or is there another problem?

Comment: What exactly is your desired output?

Comment: @JackFleeting I want the table of Small Residential Storage ONLY in a clean tabular format that I can export to a csv file.

Comment: @GabbeHags Hi, I just added my current output to the last paragraph now. The content is correct, but I would like to have a header added and also transform everything to a tabular format so that I can export to csv. The header should be in the <thead>...<thead>

Comment: So is this the output you want? ```<thead>Small Residential Storage<thead> <tr>
<td>Step Status</td>
<td>Waitlist</td>
<td>Waitlist</td>
<td>Waitlist</td>
<td>Waitlist</td>
</tr>```

Comment: @GabbeHags Sorry for the confusion, I want a result when you select the budget category equal to Small Residential Storage. Let me add the image of the output table that I want to the post.

Comment: @GabbeHags Please take a look at the picture link I just added. I am really just hope to get the whole table when tbody is Small Residential Storage.

Comment: Which part are you struggling with, exactly? Also, please do not share code/data as images. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/11301900.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it can be done with pandas, with these changes to your code above:

```
import pandas as pd

#get the headers
tab = soup.find('table',{'class': 'table'}).find_all('tr',{'class': 'head-row'})
headers=[]
for h in tab[0].find_all('td'):
   headers.append(h.text)
```

and create a dataframe

```
final = []
for res in results:
    tmp = []
    for r in res:
        if not 'NavigableString' in str(type(r)):
            tmp.append(r.text.strip())
    final.append(tmp)

df = pd.DataFrame(final,columns=headers)
df
```

Output looks like the table you want.

Comment: Hi Jack, is it possible to add another row to the dataset -- incentive rates (Small Residential Storage only)? For example, it is all at $0.25/Wh now for Small Residential Storage.

Comment: @FiFiFiona - Not sure what you mean; can you post a sample row like that?

Comment: Hi Jack, thank you for responding. The code in the next comment actually worked perfectly for my situation. It added two rows to the dataframe, which comes from the second table of incentive rates (ie, 0.25,0.25,0.25,0.25)

Answer (score 0):

```
row1 = soup.find_all('table',{'class': 'table'})[1].find_all('tr',{'class': 'head-row'})[1]
line1=[]
for h in row1.find_all('td'):
   line1.append(h.text)
row2 = soup.find_all('table',{'class': 'table'})[1].find_all('tr',{'class': ''})[3]
line2=[]
for h in row2.find_all('td'):
   line2.append(h.text)
df1=pd.DataFrame([line1,line2], columns=headers)
df2=df.append(df1,ignore_index=True)
df2
```

Comment: Try explaining how your code solves the problem posted by OP.

Comment: It worked!!! I successfully added the new rows of incentive rates of $0.25. Thanks Bear, love you so much!